# @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE) is deprecated. What would be alternative?

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

In sonarqube, I get code smell for using `@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)` inside my Bean class. I checked the Spring documentation and this information is also mentioned there. However I do not see the alternative for this.

Could anyone please help to remove this code smell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `autowire` option now does nothing, so just remove it.

As [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#autowire--) say:

> Deprecated as of 5.1, since `@Bean` factory method argument resolution and
> `@Autowired` processing supersede name/type-based bean property injection

Comment: Thanks @OrangeDog for your help. Before  marking your answer as "Accepted " I will compile the code after removing it.  The problem is that in master branch only we have configured the quality gates. So will run the build again(after removing as per your suggestion)  and check whether sonarqube is showing it as Code Smell Type)and will update soon. I have got some interesting conversation too here about this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21814

Comment: Much thanks @OrangeDog. It worked and did not give any error after removing it. Marked your answer as 'Accepted'.